# Generics in Boo - Is there an equivalent of the C# where clause

Tags: generics, where-clause, boo

Is there a way in Boo to express some constaints on generic types as we can do using the where clause in C#?

In short, how to write?:

```
class MyClass<T>
    where T:Icomparable<T>
    {...}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.
The syntax is the same as declaring base types:

```
class MyClass[of T(IComparable of T)]
```

Or, for other constraints:

```
class MyClass[of T1(class, constructor), T2(struct)]
```

I think that the current development version of Boo doesn't support generic type parameter constraints that refer to themselves or to other generic type parameters; I might be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. See:

- http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/browse_thread/thread/5ff37c89fa717bb7
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/BOO-1230
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/BOO-935